# Building Doxygen from source now requires Git? Can this be skipped?

Tags: git, doxygen

I'm upgrading from Doxygen 1.8.11 to 1.8.16, both built from source on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 in this case, but expected across various distros and versions going back at least to 2014), and I'm getting this error:

```
...

-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_NONCONST_INPUT
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_NONCONST_INPUT - Success
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_CONST_INPUT
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_CONST_INPUT - Failed
CMake Error at /home/<snip/>/build64/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Git (missing: GIT_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/<snip/>/build64/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/<snip/>/build64/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindGit.cmake:77 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/git_watcher.cmake:72 (find_package)
  libversion/CMakeLists.txt:11 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Seems that building Doxygen from source now expects a Git executable.  I'd like to avoid adding another dependency to our build notes.  What does it need Git for, and can I bypass it?

[EDIT:  Looks like Doxygen 1.8.15 builds fine without Git, so this change was introduced in 1.8.16 (the current latest release). ]

Comment: It's due to this commit: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/4ad23e5d18fc294e00844fd8557f8c5dd6254d6e as part of libversion, for populating the version perhaps?  I don't see any easy bypass but I haven't looked closely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1.8.16 version git is required but in the master version this restriction has been lifted:

- issue "git executable required" (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7285)
- fix "issue #7285 git executable required" (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/7291)

The fix consists of removing the word "REQUIRED" in cmake/git_watcher.cmake so the line:

```
    find_package(Git QUIET REQUIRED)
```

will be:

```
    find_package(Git QUIET)
```